# "Python makedirs makedirs" and "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" issues

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, automator

I work for a photography studio that shoots and retouches thousands of images per day. The studio has been moving files manually for many years and we experience a lot of user error placing the files/folders in the wrong place.  To help eliminate this I created a Python script (run via Apple Automator droplet application) which: 1. moves the files from the photographer's computer to the file server, 2. creates new directories if they do not already exist and 3. does name versioning changes on the file names if files with the same name already exist.

Here is the script:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
destinationPath = '/Volumes/extensis/product'

def updateName(name, incrementCounter):
    bsc = name[:19]
    seq = name[19:20]
    ext = name[20:]
    try:
        seq_new = int(seq)
        if incrementCounter:
            seq_new = seq_new + 1
    except ValueError:
        seq_new = 1
    name = bsc + str(seq_new).zfill(1) + ext
    return name

def makeSureCounterIsNumeric(name):
    return updateName(name, False)

def incrementCounter(name):
    return updateName(name, True)

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    name = os.path.basename(f)
    newdir = os.path.join(destinationPath, name[:1], name[:5], name[:10], name[:15])
    print newdir
    if not os.path.exists(newdir):
        os.makedirs(newdir)
    name = makeSureCounterIsNumeric(name)
    while os.path.isfile(os.path.join(newdir,name)):
        name = incrementCounter(name)
    subprocess.call(['cp', f, os.path.join(newdir,name)])
```

This is working great on MOST computers without issue.  Some computers can't run the application at all and get a python makedirs/permission denied error.  Some computers have been able to run the application for a period of time and then all of a sudden have this same error. Sometimes this error clears if we restart the computer, but not always.  Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 31 in <module> 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", Line 150, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode) 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", Line 150, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode) 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", Line 150, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode) 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", Line 150, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode) 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", Line 157, in mkdirs mkdirs(name, mode) 
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Volumes/extensis/product'
```

We have confirmed that all local machines are running the same version of the OS/python, all have admin permissions for their individual machines, all are connecting to the same file server address, and everyone has the correct permissions to access/modify the server location.  They can even manually make the directories or move files to this location without issue.

I also found some people on StackOverflow mentioning that the "/" used in the volume path can cause these issues because it refers to root folders, but I have tried all variants of the path.  With "/", without "/" and the above is the only variation that I have been able to run successfully.  The other variants either throw the permissions error or appear to run successfully but no files have been moved.

We have done a bunch of research without any answers.  We've talked with our local IT department and software devs and nobody knows anything different to look at.  The only thing they have suggested is that perhaps it is just a Mac-to-Windows issue and might not be anything we can fix.  That doesn't help.

Comment: Is the program running _as administrator_ on all computers?

Comment: So `/Volumes/extensis` is a remote filesystem?  Perhaps some computers occasionally have (very brief) connection problems?

Comment: @JohnGordon 1. I'm newish to programming so unsure how to know if it is running as admin on all computers.  All users are admin users of their computers.

Comment: 2. The file server is local within the building.  We connect via smb://ip.address or dns.  I believe someone here mentioned that same thing about brief connection problems.  Wouldn't those resolve with a computer restart?  and this is also when we've tested manually moving files without issue.